# paypal chained payments on my website

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have no experience in integrating Paypal, so I'm sorry if my questions seems a little bit odd..

I have tried for the last 48 hours to read Paypal API docs, but I can't figure out how to achieve what I'm looking for:

I want to use the chained payment option on my website,

but I don't want to host the purchase form etc on my website,

I want to put a purchase button that will redirect to paypal's payment page, where there will be two options:
- Pay with Paypal account
- Pay with credit card

can anyone reference me to what should I do?

thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read through the [Adaptive Payments developer guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-accounts/integration-guide/ACIntroduction/), and then take a look at the [Pay API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) specifically.